# Self-referring to males in father field and females in mother field in model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, models

I'm developing a database of a certain animals in Rails and I want to have "Father" and "Mother" fields.

This is probably not a big deal, but I want the user to be able to select ONLY MALES in Father field and ONLY FEMALES in Mother field, then validate it (just to be sure). Right now, however, the user gets both males and females when selecting from the animal's table.

This could probably be worked around pretty easy, but how about database? How to define this special kind of relationship in database? And what is the preferred way on Rails side? Should I implement a method, that then would be something like AnimalName.females?

Additional info:

`Database Backend: PostgreSQL`

Comment: Can you add details of your current schema and associations please (just the parts relevant to this question).

Comment: Currently, there are just `name:string`, `sex:integer`, `father:references` and `mother:references` fields and `children_count` counter_cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Rails side, you could use a custom validator to ensure an `Animal`'s `father` is a male (and mother a female). I don't know much about your specific models, but here's an example:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Animal"
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => "Animal"

  validate :ensure_mother_and_father_are_correct_gender

  private

  def ensure_mother_and_father_are_correct_gender
    if father.gender != "male"
      errors.add(:base, "Father is not a male")
    end

    if mother.gender != "female"
      errors.add(:base, "Mother is not a female")
    end
  end

end
```

That will prevent your `Animal` record from being saved if the wrong gender parent is provided. You'll likely have to introduce some kind of validation on the interface-side as well -- or at least option restriction, for example if you're selecting their parents from a drop down list, restrict the options given to only males and females:

`<%= collection_select :father, Animal.where(:species => "monkey", :gender => "male"), ... %>` or whatever.

Comment: Probably the KISSest answer. Thank you!